# subset() drops attributes on vectors; how to maintain/persist them?

Tags: r, vector, attributes, subset, persistent

Let's say I have a vector where I've set a few attributes:

```
vec <- sample(50:100,1000, replace=TRUE)
attr(vec, "someattr") <- "Hello World"
```

When I subset the vector, the attributes are dropped. For example:

```
tmp.vec <- vec[which(vec > 80)]
attributes(tmp.vec) # Now NULL
```

Is there a way to, subset and persist attributes without having to save them to another temporary object?

Bonus: Where would one find documentation of this behaviour?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would write a method for `[` or `subset()` (depending on how you are subsetting) and arrange for that to preserve the attributes. That would need a `"class"` attribute also adding to your vector so that dispatch occurs.

```
vec <- 1:10
attr(vec, "someattr") <- "Hello World"
class(vec) <- "foo"
```

At this point, subsetting removes attributes:

```
> vec[1:5]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

If we add a method `[.foo` we can preserve the attributes:

```
`[.foo` <- function(x, i, ...) {
    attrs <- attributes(x)
    out <- unclass(x)
    out <- out[i]
    attributes(out) <- attrs
    out
}
```

Now the desired behaviour is preserved

```
> vec[1:5]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
attr(,"someattr")
[1] "Hello World"
attr(,"class")
[1] "foo"
```

---

And the answer to the bonus question:

From `?"["` in the details section:

*Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except names, dim and dimnames.*

Comment: Thx for the answer! btw for subsetting lists one may include before transferring attributes to out, `if(!is.null(attrs$names)) attrs$names = names(x)[i] ` to subset list names also. Otherwise it will likely cause an error.

Comment: There's now a package [sticky](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/sticky) which does this behind the scenes, though I'm unsure how active the repo is and there are some limitations.

Comment: @Hadley Wickham also has [a section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#methods) explaining how this is done in more detail, as well as a helper generic `sloop::reconstruct()` from the yet-unreleased [sloop](https://github.com/hadley/sloop) package.

Comment: and lastly, I just kicked off a discussion on how to best do this in general over at [community.rstudio.com](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-retain-attributes-from-an-s3-class-on-subsetting-and-should-i)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a similar answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990649/retain-attributes-and-classes-when-subsetting-rrapply/) @G. Grothendieck, you can use `collapse::fsubset` see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/collapse/man/fsubset.html).

```
library(collapse)
#tmp_vec <- fsubset(vec, vec > 80)
tmp_vec <- sbt(vec, vec > 80)     # Shortcut for fsubset
attributes(tmp_vec) 
# $someattr
# [1] "Hello World"
```